# bayes rule -> practical application with Sharp IR sensor

Tags: python, robot

I have a robot using IR and Sonar sensors for measuring distances. I build an occupancy map/grid.
So far I use a simple integer based system to "calculate" the probability of a cell being occupied. Something like +1 if sensor hit and -1 for all calls between 0 and sensor reading-1. If the number in the array for one cell if above the threshold the cell is counted as occupied and via versa for unoccupied. All between in uncertain. (a bit more complex but based on this idea)

I now wonder if it is worth to use a Bayes theorem based solution for this (first code snip below). As most people do it this way the answer is most likely yes :-).

What do p1 and p2 mean in this specific example - let's say for an IR distance sensor? I understand the examples when the theorem is explained. But somehow I can't translate them to the IR sensor situation. (my mind got a bit stuck here)
I have no clue what and how to estimate the values I should put in there and how to apply them to my array/map.

Would be nice if someone could enlighten me :-)
If somehow possible with some pseudo code.

Below also the class for my current map handling.

Thanks
Robert

Bayes functions -- but how to apply?

```
def pos(p0, p1, p2):
    return (p0 * p1)/(p0 * p1 + (1-p0) * (1-p2))

def neg(p0, p1, p2):
    return (p0 * (1-p1))/(p0 * (1-p1) + (1-p0) * p2)
```

My current Map class:

```
templateData = {
    'MapWidth' : 800,
    'MapHeight': 600,
    'StartPosX' : 500,
    'StartPosY' : 300,
    'StartTheta' : 0,
    'Resolution' : 5,
    'mapThresholdFree' : 126,
    'mapThresholdOcc' : 130,
    'EmptyValue' : 128,
    'mapMaxOcc' : 255,
    'mapMaxFree' : 0,
    'ServoPos' : 0,
    'CurrentPosX' : 0,
    'CurrentPosY' : 0,
    'CurrentTheta' : 0
}

templateData["MapHeight"] = templateData["MapHeight"] / templateData["Resolution"]
templateData["MapWidth"] = templateData["MapWidth"] / templateData["Resolution"]
templateData["StartPosX"] = templateData["StartPosX"] / templateData["Resolution"]
templateData["StartPosY"] = templateData["StartPosY"] / templateData["Resolution"]

#map
map=robotmap.NewRobotMap(templateData["MapWidth"],templateData["MapHeight"], templateData["Resolution"], templateData["StartPosX"],templateData["StartPosY"], templateData["StartTheta"], templateData["ServoPos"],templateData["mapMaxOcc"],templateData["mapMaxFree"],templateData["EmptyValue"])
map.clear()

class NewRobotMap(object): 
    def __init__(self, sizeX, sizeY, Resolution, RobotPosX, RobotPosY, RobotTheta, ServoPos, mapMaxOcc, mapMaxFree, EmptyValue):
        self.sizeX = sizeX 
        self.sizeY = sizeY 
        self.RobotPosX = int(RobotPosX)
        self.RobotPosY = int(RobotPosY)
        self.mapResolution = int(Resolution)
        self.StartPosX = int(RobotPosX)
        self.StartPosY = int(RobotPosY)
        self.RobotTheta = float(RobotTheta)
        self.EmptyValue = EmptyValue
        self.ServoPos = ServoPos
        self.mapMaxOcc = mapMaxOcc
        self.mapMaxFree = mapMaxFree
    def clear(self):
        self.RobotMap = [[self.EmptyValue for i in xrange(self.sizeY)] for j in xrange(self.sizeX)]
    def updateMap(self ,x ,y , Val):
        oldval = self.RobotMap[x][y]
        self.RobotMap[x][y]=self.RobotMap[x][y] + Val
        if self.RobotMap[x][y] > self.mapMaxOcc:
            self.RobotMap[x][y] = self.mapMaxOcc
        elif self.RobotMap[x][y] < self.mapMaxFree:
            self.RobotMap[x][y] = self.mapMaxFree            
        return oldval, self.RobotMap[x][y]
    def updateRobot(self,theta,x,y):
        self.RobotTheta = float(theta)
        self.RobotPosX = int(round(self.StartPosX + float(int(x)/self.mapResolution), 0))
        self.RobotPosY = int(round(self.StartPosY - float(int(y)/self.mapResolution),0))
    def getRobotPos(self):
        return self.RobotPosX, self.RobotPosY
    def display(self):
        s = [[str(e) for e in row] for row in self.RobotMap]
        lens = [len(max(col, key=len)) for col in zip(*s)]
        fmt = '\t'.join('{{:{}}}'.format(x) for x in lens)
        table = [fmt.format(*row) for row in s]
        print '\n'.join(table)
    def updateServoPos(self, newServoPos):
        self.ServoPos = newServoPos
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow. But Bayesian methods almost always require you to collect a whole bunch of data first in order to calculate a prior probability (Bayes' formula being `Pr(A|B) = Pr(B|A)Pr(A) / ( Pr(B|A)Pr(A) + Pr(B|not A)Pr(not A) )`) You need to already have estimates for `Pr(A)`, `Pr(not A)`, `Pr(B|A)` and `Pr(B|not A)`.

Comment: Hmm, ok. What I do at the moment is to take the current probability and add/subtract something. So I don't need to keep a history. I thought I can translate the bayes approach to something like this.

Comment: I think that what you might be looking for is a [Kalman filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter).

Comment: Thanks I will look into Kalman filter too. How I understood the Bayes approach was that I could calculate something like "based on the current probability - let's say 0.2 (so most likely unoccupied) the current positive reading is unlikely (based on positive / false positive ratio) - so the probability raises only a little".

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But determining the current probability usually involves calculating frequency within a sample. If you have information about the underlying distribution through some other means, than that would work just fine.

Comment: What does frequency within a sample mean in your answer? Is it related to the sampling frequency of the sensor?

Answer (score 0):

In `pos`:

- `p0` is the prior probability that an object is there. This would probably require knowing in advance the density of objects in the map.
- `p1` is the probability of a sensor hit given that an object is there (IOW a true positive)
- `p2` is the probability of no sensor hit given that an object is not there (a true negative)

Now `1 - p2` is therefore the probability of a sensor hit given that an object is not there (a false positive). Additionally, `1 - p0` is the probability of no object being there. If we plug these values into Bayes' Rule, we get:

```
Pr(Object|Hit) = Pr(Hit|Object)Pr(Object) / ( Pr(Hit|Object)Pr(Object) + Pr(No Hit|Object)Pr(No Object)

= p1 * p0 / ( p1 * p0 + (1 - p2) * (1 - p0) )
```

Which is the `pos()` function you gave.

*Note:* In the event that you don't know the density of objects in the map beforehand, you can use `p0 = 0.5`, in which case the equation simplifies to:

```
Pr(Hit|Object) / ( Pr(Hit|Object) + Pr(No Hit|Object) )
= p1 / (p1 + (1-p2))
```

Comment: Tanks a lot for your explanation. As I need to start with an unknown desity I don't see an advantage if tis aproach compared to pure hit/no hit counting - maybe extended by different weight for hit vs. no hit. (beside always having a a probability between 0 an 1). Do I miss something?

Comment: OK. I can't edit anymore. Sorry for the typos in my answer above.